# Copy array and push one element from another array to every copy

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two arrays, let’s say `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [x, y, z].`

How can I create third array like this `c = [[1, 2, 3, x], [1, 2, 3, y], [1, 2, 3, z]]` from them?

Thanks.

Comment: you are likely to get better response if you post what have you done so for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` method on `b` and then `concat()` each element on  `a`.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3], b = ['x', 'y', 'z']

var result = b.map(e => a.concat(e));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` to do this, like so:

```js
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = ["x", "y", "z"];
var c = b.map(function (elem) {
    return a.concat(elem);
});
console.log(c);
```